# Looking for mass email delivery service

Tags: email

I'm looking for a solutions to deliver newsletters through a reliable service provider. Currently, I'm using [Lyris List Manager](http://www.lyris.com/solutions/listmanager/) software on my dedicated server to send out newsletters to opted in recipients.

We don't have the knowledge to troubleshoot issues coming down the pipe, so we're looking for a hosted solution to manage our mail delivery. Does anyone know of or have any experience with mass mail delivery services? Lyris offers Lyris HQ for a hosted solution, but I'd like to know what else is out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Campaign Monitor](http://www.campaignmonitor.com/) is pretty awesome, in my experience.

[ExactTarget](http://exacttarget.com/) is another commonly used service.

Answer (score 1):

Mail Chimp.

Heres a review for it by paul stamatiou when he used it for skribit: http://paulstamatiou.com/2009/03/25/review-mailchimp-email-marketing

Comment: Another vote for MailChimp.  It's very easy to set up and generally very slick.

Answer (score 0):

I think subscribe the service from the providers who do that for living would be a best approach. having it hosted on the dedicate server on your own sometime may trigger the ISP to warn you that you violate their spam policy, or something like this. It's true that mass delivering newsletters is a type of spamming from ISP's eyes.

Answer (score 0):

My company uses Rackspace's Mailtrust. I believe the two companies recently merged, as their website now claims "Mailtrust is now Rackspace" or something similar. It works well and includes Outlook Web Access for us. I do not know if they have any other interface. I'm not the biggest fan of OWA, but it works pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Blue Sky Factory](http://www.blueskyfactory.com). They bought our old Mass Mailer, so we got our old rates. I'm not too sure what Blue Sky's rates are, but the interface for reporting and segmentation is GREAT.

Answer (score 0):

We use [Emma](http://myemma.com/). What's nice about Emma is they have a whole interface for creating and customizing newsletters on the web, and they're pretty cheap if you want them to create something new. They also have all the standard features: audience tracking, multiple lists, etc. We've used [Constant Contact](http://www.constantcontact.com/) and [Bronto](http://www.bronto.com/) in the past, and looked into a lot of others like [Vertical Response](http://www.verticalresponse.com/) and [MailChimp](http://www.mailchimp.com/) and found Emma to be the easiest to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you are specifically turning an RSS feed into an email newsletter, check out http://FeedmailPro.com

It's a lot less expensive than solutions mentioned above.